# Hide quantity fields in cart for specific products in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product-quantity

I Would like to hide the quantity field from one specific product category in cart page.

The "Sold Individually" doesn't help me because I have a plugin that must be disabled to work.

Is it possible? Any track will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will hide the product quantity field on cart page:

1) for a specific product category *(that you will define in this code)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'hide_quantity_input_field', 20, 2 );
function hide_quantity_input_field( $args, $product ) {
    // Here set your product categories in the array (can be either an ID, a slug, a name or an array)
    $categories = array('t-shirts','shoes');

    // Handling product variation
    $the_id = $product->is_type('variation') ? $product->get_parent_id() : $product->get_id();

    // Only on cart page for a specific product category
    if( is_cart() && has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $the_id ) ){
        $input_value = $args['input_value'];
        $args['min_value'] = $args['max_value'] = $input_value;
    }
    return $args;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works. 
It will also handle product variations added to cart.

2) for specific product IDs *(that you will define in this code)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'hide_quantity_input_field', 20, 2 );
function hide_quantity_input_field( $args, $product ) {
    // Here set your product IDs in the array
    $product_ids = array(37,40,70);

    // Handling product variation
    $the_id = $product->is_type('variation') ? $product->get_parent_id() : $product->get_id();

    // Only on cart page for a specific product category
    if( is_cart() && in_array( $the_id, $product_ids ) ){
        $input_value = $args['input_value'];
        $args['min_value'] = $args['max_value'] = $input_value;
    }
    return $args;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works. 
It will also handle product variations added to cart.

Comment: if you have more than one product categories? For now its only two categories. cat1 cat2 for example. Thanks

Comment: @GeorgeCh Updated my code to handle multiple product categories.