# How to include multiple product ids in a Woocommerce action

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, if-statement, woocommerce

How can we include multiple product id in the  `if ($product->get_id()=="15757"){`

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'ts_woocommerce_quantity_selected_number', 10, 2 );
  
function ts_woocommerce_quantity_selected_number( $args, $product ) {
 // global $product;
   if ( ! is_cart() ) {
 if ($product->get_id()=="15757"){
      $args['input_value'] = 5; // Start from this value (default = 1) 
      $args['max_value'] = 15; // Maximum quantity (default = -1)
      $args['min_value'] = 5; // Minimum quantity (default = 0)
      $args['step'] = 5; // Increment or decrement by this value (default = 1)
 }
   } else {
 if ($product->get_id()=="15757"){
      // Cart's 'min_value' is 0
      $args['max_value'] = 15; 
      $args['step'] = 5; 
      $args['min_value'] = 5;
 }
   }
  
   return $args; 
}
```

We tried this but it doesn't work  `if ($product->get_id()=="15757,15758,15759"){`

Comment: Make use of an array, as shown in: [Hide quantity fields in cart for specific products in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51102798/hide-quantity-fields-in-cart-for-specific-products-in-woocommerce-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple product Ids you can use `in_array()` for an array of product Ids… Now in your code you need to add the "product ids" condition first like:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'ts_woocommerce_quantity_selected_number', 10, 2 );
function ts_woocommerce_quantity_selected_number( $args, $product ) {
    $product_ids = array("15757", "15758"); // Here the array of product Ids

    if ( in_array( $product->get_id(), $product_ids ) ) {
        // In cart
        if ( ! is_cart() ) {
            $args['input_value'] = 5; // Start from this value (default = 1) 
            $args['max_value'] = 15; // Maximum quantity (default = -1)
            $args['min_value'] = 5; // Minimum quantity (default = 0)
            $args['step'] = 5; // Increment or decrement by this value (default = 1)
        } 
        // Not in cart
        else {
            // Cart's 'min_value' is 0
            $args['max_value'] = 15; 
            $args['step'] = 5; 
            $args['min_value'] = 5;
        }
    }
    return $args; 
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Related: [Hide quantity fields in cart for specific products in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51102798/hide-quantity-fields-in-cart-for-specific-products-in-woocommerce-3)

Comment: this helped alot thank you so much and worked fine, but why did you You need to add the product id condition first, what is the difference between that and between our code where we check first if its cart ? ,, what is the difference ?

Comment: In your case you are using the same product Id in both place of a IF ELSE statement… So in this case you will put the order ID first only in an IF statement. To target multiple product Ids (array of ids) you will use `in_array()`…

Comment: we got your point and this doesn't affect the function to check if its cart first or to check if its the matched product id first